# How to stop multiple threads with Tkinter button

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I'm trying to close 2 threads at once using a tkinter button, but nothing I've tried so far seams to work. The database thread keeps writing data to the database (represented by the data_acquisition_for_database function) and the tkinter window stays opened.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from _thread import start_new_thread
from threading import Timer
import time

def data_acquisition_for_database(update_period):
    while TRUE:
        print("Database thread")
        time.sleep(update_period)

def update_GUI():
    Timer(data_representation_update_period, update_GUI).start()
    global update_timer
    update_timer = True

main_window = Tk()
data_acquisition_update_period = 5
data_representation_update_period = 5
quit_button = Button(main_window, text="QUIT", command=quit)
quit_button.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=NSEW)
main_window.update()
start_new_thread(data_acquisition_MB_to_DB,     (data_acquisition_update_period,))

update_timer = False
update_GUI()

while TRUE:
    if update_timer:
        print("GUI thread")
        update_timer = False
    main_window.update_idletasks()
    main_window.update()
```

I have tried quit(), exit(), sys.exit(0) but nothing kills both threads.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: is `TRUE` a variable or `True`?

Comment: It's `True`, it's not a variable, just a statement to keep the thread going